# Google Charts Library not loading

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Sometimes the Google Charts library won't load. The following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at Object.google.G.K.T.Ak (loader.js:225)
at Object.google.G.load (loader.js:226)
```

Here is my page code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$( function() {

    // wait for page to load
    window.addEventListener('load', loadGoogle, false);

    function loadGoogle() {
        // define callback in load statement
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': loadApp});
    }

    function loadApp() {
        // do some amazing stuff
    }

} );
```

Some days it works, other days it doesn't.

I have also tried to put everything in my page as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { packages: [ 'corechart', 'table', 'bar', 'controls' ]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( function(e) { alert('callback');});
</script>
```

When I do that I get a different set of errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Promise.resolve is not a function
    at loader.js:239
    at loader.js:243
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Bad version: current
    at loader.js:224
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Callback doesn't work on it's own either. It actually never gets to the point of calling the callback for some reason.

Comment: The full JS file is ~3200 lines of code so that won't work :). Maybe I will try on the host page.

Comment: Your "everything in my page" works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/jsc23sk6/  Does that page work for you?  If not, I would suspect your browser or an addon is acting up.